# My HTC one M9+ doesn't perform background tasks when idle but push notifications work

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, htc, firefox-for-android, background-process, htc-one-m9

I have an HTC One M9+. After the update to Android 6 (two years ago?) it stopper performing background tasks. For example:

[FeedMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seazon.feedme&hl=en_US) - an offline RSS-reader. 100 000+ installs. It is set to download new articles every 2 hours. Doesn't happen.

[SMS Backup+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync&hl=en) - backs up your SMS etc to GMail. 5 000 000+ installs. It is set to backup every day. Doesn't happen.

[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&hl=en) - copies folder to cloud storage. 500 000+ installs. No schedules are run.

These apps are not battery (doze) optimised. Adding / removing them to doze optimization doesn't make a difference in the behavior

Push notifications from Facebook and similar work as expected. It is like cron or a similar service stopped working when I updated to Android 6. Does anyone know if HTC made something special with their version of Android? Any workarounds?

Edit: I can add another another popular app to the list, Pusbullet (1 000 000+ downloads). I also have a Sony Experia with exactly the same programs on, and there it works flawlessy. It also runs Android 6.

Edit: I can add Firefox to the list above. Even though I have logged in to my FF account and confirmed the login it doesn't sync.